# git, understand local repository when multiple branches

Tags: git

I had a ruby on rails project, after a while i decided to put it under git, so i change the directory to the project root and i issued a

```
git init
```

command. Then i pushed it onto my bitbucket git repository.

The effect of `git init` has been to have a .git directory created inside my project, and i've understood that this is the local git repository. 
Now i want to branch my project to add some feature.

My first idea is to create another project directory for the branch, so that is possible to work on the 'master' or on the 'new_feature_x' branch the same.

But what about the git repository inside my master branch?

Am I supposed to create another directory with another local git repository? 
Shouldn't the local repository be shared among the different branches of a project?

Comment: Read [this](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching). It'll explain what git branching is, why you want it and how to use it.

Comment: Using **`git`** means no more creating directories `mycode-old` `mycode-old2` and `mycode-old-5august` ;-)

Comment: simont, i know exactly why i want to branch, and that document is infact very detailed on why branching, while i need to know how branching exactly works. It seems that git changes the files in your working directory when you issue the checkout command, so there is no need to create a second directory. Moreover, it would be difficult to do so if you have put your repo inside the project directory

Answer (score 2):

The `.git` directory is independent of your working copy, it will not be affected by any normal branching, committing, and merging operations you do with Git. You can still work on both your `master` branch and a `feature` branch at the same time.

To make your `feature` branch and check it out into your working copy directory, use

```
git checkout -b <feature branch name> master
```

Then you can switch between `master` and `feature` as much as you want:

```
git checkout master
git checkout feature
```